# Extract Required info from json nested nested loops

Tags: php, json

I am using php to fetch live rates for cryptocurrency from coin market cap api. Here is the response that i get from the api. I want to extract the USD price from this nested response. I tried this :

```
$rate = json_decode($response,true);
echo $rate['data'][0]['quotes'][0]['USD'][0];
```

But it didn't worked. The json response that i got is :

```
{
  "status": {
    "timestamp": "2020-09-26T12:59:24.147Z",
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_message": null,
    "elapsed": 13,
    "credit_count": 1,
    "notice": null
  },
  "data": {
    "BTC": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "slug": "bitcoin",
      "num_market_pairs": 9251,
      "date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "tags": [
        "mineable",
        "pow",
        "sha-256",
        "store-of-value",
        "state-channels"],
        
      "max_supply": 21000000,
      "circulating_supply": 18500450,
      "total_supply": 18500450,
      "is_active": 1,
      "platform": null,
      "cmc_rank": 1,
      "is_fiat": 0,
      "last_updated": "2020-09-26T12:58:38.000Z",
      "quote": {
        "USD": {
          "price": 10707.7229962,
          "volume_24h": 20866014910.9822,
          "percent_change_1h": -0.156013,
          "percent_change_24h": 0.675761,
          "percent_change_7d": -2.97789,
          "market_cap": 198097693905.04828,
          "last_updated": "2020-09-26T12:58:38.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way if you need to grab the **USD** price only of **BTC**,

```
echo $rate['data']['BTC']['quote']['USD']['price'];
```

Otherwise need to loop through the API response and grab the value from it but the index path `['quote']['USD']['price']` should be more or less the same as I pointed.

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/gi7jB

Comment: @JohnSmith glad it helps you somehow, best of luck sir :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of indexes. When using associative arrays (hashmaps) you can not use numeric indexes.

```
foreach ($rate['data'] as $currency => $currencyData) {
    echo "$currency: {$currencyData['quote']['USD']['price']}\n";
}
```

> BTC: 10707.7229962